# Empty Table View in UIPopover

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uitableview, uipopovercontroller

I am having some hard time with TableView insite UIPopover, the table is simply empty, even though it is a static table view.

code:

```
- (IBAction)settingsBtnPressed:(id)sender {
if(self.pop.isPopoverVisible) {
    [self.pop dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
} else {
    //SettingsViewController *s = [[SettingsViewController alloc] init];
    SettingsViewController *s = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"settings"];
    s.brain = self.brain;
    self.pop = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:s];
    [self.pop setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(400, 500)];
    [self.pop presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
}
}
```

Attaching screenshots:

[image: Grouped static table view controller defined in IB.]
[image: Result I'm getting.]

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in your debugger, can you confirm that your *s is actually pointing at an instance of SettingsViewController?

Comment: Yes, it is. Even tried to instantiate it as type `id` and checked `[var class]`. Clearly stated `SettingsViewController`.

Comment: Have you wired up the table view in IB including wiring the delegate and the data source to the files owner?

Comment: Well, I didn't, it has been done automatically. When I left-click on the VC in IB, it says that delegate and dataSource, indeed, is SettingsViewController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you implemented methods like `cellForRow:atIndex:`, `numberOfSections:inTableView:` and `numberOfRows:inSection` ?

Comment: I actually have and that was the problem! It is static view and therefore I needed to delete those methods and let the view display itself according to IB.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are not using `UITableViewController` but rather `UIViewController` in your header file.